# Pull FullContact Ruby Gem Photos?

Tags: ruby, api, rest, rubygems, fullcontact

https://github.com/fullcontact/fullcontact-api-ruby

I'm trying to use the FullContact API Wrapper for Ruby (it's a gem) instead of the pure REST API. I'm trying to figure out how to grab the person's profile pictures from email address. I know how to get them from the REST API that responds with JSON, but not sure what the example code there is doing.

`person = FullContact.person(email: "brawest@gmail.com")` (pulled from example in the Github linked)

So now how do I retrieve profile pictures from `person`? What data type is it storing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FullContact gem uses Hashie, and from a call it returns a [Hashie::Rash](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#rash) object.

So if you were trying to access photos:

```
> person = FullContact.person(email: "email")
=> [#<Hashie::Rash contact_info=#<Hashie::Rash family_name=...
> person.photos
=> [#<Hashie::Rash is_primary=true type="facebook" type_id="facebook" type_name="Facebook"...
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, man! Actually got it a little before this, but I really appreciate it :)